# Не работает datepicker в bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker

Не отображается календарь при клике на иконку. Т.е. кроме как стилизации инпута функционала datepicker нет.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">form</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Вызов:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

и все что я подключил:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Вот что гласит консоль:

```
    GET file:///D:/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:95 GET file:///D:/path/to/jquery.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:96 GET file:///D:/path/to/moment-with-locales.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:97 GET file:///D:/path/to/bootstrap/js/transition.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:98 GET file:///D:/path/to/bootstrap/js/collapse.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:99 GET file:///D:/path/to/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:100 GET file:///D:/path/to/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
bootstrap.js:8 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.js:8
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.js:8
index.html:90 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.html:90
```

Comment: Значит, не правильно подключаете. Что консоль говорит?

Comment: на сколько я понял - ничего. т.к. иконка календаря вообще не кликабельная.

Comment: а разве не должен по дефолту работать?И каким образом это сделать корректно?Не силен в js

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: а что для Вас означает ошибка `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

После добавления строк выше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помогло тем что иконка стала кликабельна. Но по прежнему ошибки синтаксиса и еще, на сколько я понял не правильно подключен jquery:

bootstrap.js:8 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.js:8
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.js:8
index.html:92 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: осталась одна ошибка)):

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.js:8

Comment: заново поставил все ссылки, но всё равно календарь не всплывает. в консоли ошибок нет. Может дело в том что бутстрап у меня локально а не через cdn?

Comment: jquery поставил этой версии а бутстрап локально ставил изначально этой версии и закоментил ссылку на бутстрап более старой версии, все остальные ссылки из вашего ответа не трогал закоментил только эту:
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

и всё равно не работает, и в консоли пусто

Comment: каким классом идет сам календарь? .dropdown-menu?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68567/discussion-between-nirolo1-and-).